# Winforms problem with codepage "?" char instead of apostrophe '

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, character-encoding

In .NET 3.5, I have a Winform with a combobox in it. The datya comes from a DB2 mainframe DB. The problem is that we have a character that is not the real apostrophe. Pasted from Word I'd guess. But in our combobox, it is not diplayed correctly. It shows a question mark "?" instead.

Any idea on how could I get it to display the character as it is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should check if the character is intact in the database, or if the problem is that the code page doesn't support the character.

If the code page used in the database doesn't support the character, it has been replaced with a question mark, and the data is lost. The best you could do in that case is to try to figure out which question marks are the result of data loss, and which are supposed to be question marks, and try to recreate the data.

If the character is intact in the database, you should just need to make sure that the font used to display the text supports unicode.

Note: The character used is probably a typographic apostrophe like unicode character [U+2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! As a matter of fact, it is this caracter. And it is OK in the DB and correctly displayed through other application (Cool:Gen I think). Problem is we have requirements that specify we must use the "Microsoft Sans Seriff" font.

Comment: @ultraman69: Ok, in that case I suppose that you can just do a string replacement before putting the text in the control.